# error in node.js upload photo program

Tags: node.js

i want to develope and application in node.js where i shud b able to upload a video   in my page and store a link to that video in database(mongodb).when i click //to the link the vedio should get displayed.also i shud b able to display all the //video's uploaded in the page.I tried to code to upload phot

```
//new show photo code  
app.get('/photos', function(req, res) {
    photos.list(function(err, photo_list) {
    res.render('photos/index', {locals : {
    photos: photo_list
    }});
  });
});

app.get('/photos/new', function(req, res){
  res.render('photos/new', {
             locals: {
               title: 'New File Upload'
             }
  });
});

app.post('/photos', function(req, res) {
  req.setEncoding('binary');
  var parser = multipart.parser();
  parser.headers = req.headers;
  var ws;
  parser.onpartBegin = function(part) {
    consol.log('inside begin');
    ws = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/static/upload/photos.' + part.filename)
    ws.on('error', function(err) {
      throw err;
    });
  };
  parser.onData = function(data) {
    ws.write(data);
  };
  parser.onPartEnd = function() {
    ws.end();
    parser.close();
    console.log('file successfully uploaded');
    res.redirect('/photos');
  };
  req.on('data', function(data) { 
      console.log('shud not go here');
      parser.write(data);
  });
});
```

//can any one send me the code for the same or else find were i am doing //wrong.....answer immediately required....

Comment: thanks for helping.I have tried formidable also.the basic problem is that when i submit the form i should be able to store the path of image in database which in my case is mongodb,  and also in my page a link should be displayed which when clicked should lead me to the video file and should b able to view the video. in other words i should b able to upload and display the video on the page. I am stuck from past two days.

Comment: I also tried the code provided in  http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/12-file-uploads-using-nodejs-and-express.html#video.this code is also not working, in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) for file uploads in Node.js, it's a widely used library for such a thing.